# Mistake in interpretation of principal curvatures of hyperboloid

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Consider a hyperboloid of 1-sheet with the following parametrization:

$x = \sinh(v) \cos(\theta)$

$y = \sinh(v) \sin(\theta)$

$z = \cosh(v)$

where $v>0$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.

Without any calculation, I would guess that the principal curvatures $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ are

$\kappa_1 = \frac{1}{\sinh(v)}$, since $\sinh(v)$ is the radius of the circle when fixing $v$

and

$\kappa_1 = 0$, since when fixing $\theta$, the corresponding curve parametrized by $v$ is a straight line

However, this is certainly wrong as I know that the Gauss curvature is given by:

Gauss = $\frac{1}{|1+2\cosh(v)^2|^2}$

which is the product of $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$. So I know that my intuition is wrong, however, I don't understand where my logic fails. Where is my thinking mistake?

Comment: The curve $\theta=cste$ isn't at all a straight line, it is a hyperbola

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks. Would you agree that $\kappa_1 = 1/\sinh(v)$ though?

Comment: To be fair, I don't know right now (don't have time to do the computations). I was just pointing out at the fact that your very first intuition was evidently wrong!

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway. Feel free to add your comment as an answer as it is indeed showing my mistake.

Comment: No to the value of $\kappa_1$: Those curves are circles, but their principal normals (i.e., as curves) are not normal to the hyperboloid.

Comment: indeed, thanks @AndrewD.Hwang